# Elegant way to force two array elements when splitting a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Assume the following string:

```
$string = 'entry1_entry2';
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
list($entry1, $entry2) = explode('_', $string);
```

My question now is are there any elegant ways to force the explode (or any other function) to get 2 array items **minimum**? You could specify a third parameter to get a maximum of 2 elements but I want a minimum. If there would be a string like this:

```
$string = 'entry1';
```

The second line would give a `NOTICE` because there is only one array element. The best would be a way without checking the resulting array or the string for the presence of the seperator.

Comment: When you say "the second line" it makes me wonder if you're doing something along these lines `echo $array[0] . $array[1]`, you could just a foreach loop and totally avoid the error!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could probably use `array_pad`:

```
list($entry1, $entry2) = array_pad(explode('_', $string), 2, NULL);
```

See [array_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)

Comment: +1, but I would use NULL instead of an empty string as value;

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. Certainly depends on the context, but you probably want to be able to tell apart "foo" and "foo_"...

Comment: The difference is when do some test like `isset( $entry2 )` which is FALSE if you set the variable to NULL.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that storing the `explode` inside multiple variables is just bad practice, when you can't enforce the integrity of your data.

Should you not simply be using

```
$entries = explode($string);
```

and avoid all the unnecessary complications?